# Why is this UISearchBar getting resized?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

As shown below, my `UISearchBar` is getting resized when I tap on the search field. It animates nicely to cover the navigation bar, and then pop... it shrinks.

[image] [image]

### The setup

The `UISearchBar` is inside a vanilla `UIView` set as the `tableHeaderView`. I'm using a `UIView` (as opposed to setting the `UISearchBar` as the header) because I would like to put additional views in the header.

The view is defined in a XIB file and the `UISearchBar` is anchored to all of its borders. The constraints don't seem to matter; if I remove them, the same problem happens.

### Experiments

**Examining the view hierarchy in Reveal tells me that the `UIView` has the right size and the `UISearchBar` has width 1 (?!) when this happens**.

As an experiment, I subclassed the `UISearchBar` and made `intrinsicContentSize` return `{320,44}`. With this the `UISearchBar` shows properly, but when I press Cancel I get the following exception:

```
 *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UIView.m:8540
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

### The workaround

If I create everything by code, it just works.

```
_headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44)];
searchBar.delegate = self;
[_headerView addSubview:searchBar];

_searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
_searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
_searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchDisplayController.delegate = self;

_tableView.tableViewHeader = _headerView;
```

What is going on here? I clearly won't use nibs to work with `UISearchBar` anymore, but I would like to understand what the heck happened anyway.

Comment: Looks like there's probably an auto-layout constraint to set the cancel button and the search field to equal sizes.

Comment: @nhgrif If there is, I certainly didn't add it.

Comment: Thats why I lay everything out in code...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is in the search bar's value of `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`. It defaults to `NO` for the XIB-based view and `YES` for the code-based view. Apparently, the search controller assumes a value of YES and doesn't set up any explicit constraints when it transplants the search bar.

Setting the value to `YES` in code should fix it (verified locally).

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, even with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`, the controller does not restore the header view to it's original state on cancel. But there does seem to be a workaround. You can create an outlet to your header view and restore it yourself in `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`. I did a crude proof-of-concept (and updated my sample project):

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
    [self.searchBar removeFromSuperview];
    self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 44);
    [self.headerView addSubview:self.searchBar];
}
```

Comment: The are no autoresizing masks in the code I posted and it also works.

Comment: Yeah, but the default value of `UIViewAutoresizingNone` is still a value. And it means "don't resize", which can be translated into equivalent constraints. But don't take my word for it, try this [sample project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2183704/Search%20Bar%20Demo.zip) with and without the `self.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So my sample project didn't convince you?

Comment: Thanks Timothy. It looks like this is bug, doesn't it? It shouldn't be necessary to use `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` when using IB.

Comment: No doubt a bug. I filed a couple of bug reports with Apple. The second bug was that (at least in my updated sample project), even with `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`, the original layout is not restored after tapping Cancel. It seems that `UISearchDisplayController` makes an undocumented assumption that the search bar is the only content of the header view.

Comment: It's worse. It actually replaces your header with the UISearchBar.

Comment: Anyway to get around replacing the header?  When I get out of the search bar mode, it re-sizes to it's super view covering all other views in that view.

Comment: @James Updated my answer with a workaround that I think may work for you.

Comment: @TimothyMoose this is absolutely terrible. i've wasted hours today with this. i hate having to implement these hacks but i appreciate your help in figuring this out. has anyone made progress since this?

Comment: by the way, setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints doesn't do anything different for me, and setting it to NO makes the search bar shrink to almost nothing and then crashes the app... upvoting for pushing me further towards the idea of implementing searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch and recreating table header.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from what both @TimothyMoose and @hpique have said about setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES (yuck)

In my code I have found that if I do the following to show the searchDisplayController

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES]
```

and do the opposite when closing the searchDisplayController,

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES]
```

Then my view remains unchanged (everything goes back to what I'm expecting)

if i ***do not call*** the following line when closing

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

Then the view screws up.

The reason for this I believe is that the NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint are asserting them self and as they are the last in the constraint list, the Layout engine brakes the real constraint to satisfy the unwanted NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint constraints.

Comment: This seem to work correctly building against iOS8 beta 5, and running on 7.1, 8 beta 5

NO search bar seem to appear at all in iOS6... :( -  i believe the search bar is off the screen

Comment: and sort of on iOS6 (seems other code in the code base was interfering)